# jQuery datepicker pick date in next 7 days

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I am using jQuery date picker and want to choose a date between today's date and the next 7 days. I have it working so I can only choose a date from today on wards. I want to be able choose a date only in the next 7 days.

```
$('#datepairExample .date').datepicker({ // initializing datepicker
   startDate : "0d",
   format : "d/m/yyyy"
});
```

I am guessing there is an endDate like I have used startDate above.

Comment: Super easy documentation to read online... https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#min-max `$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({ minDate: -20, maxDate: "+1M +10D" });`

Answer (score 2):

Please, note that `startDate` and `format` don't exist: [see the available options on documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/).

Try [`maxDate`](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-maxDate), [`minDate`](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-minDate), and [`dateFormat`](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-dateFormat):

```
$('#datepairExample .date').datepicker({ // initializing datepicker
   minDate: 0,
   maxDate: "7d", // or: maxDate: "1w",
   dateFormat: "d/m/yyyy"
});
```